# React website font sizes and div sizes appearing bigger upon deployement than on local host

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

During development on local host my react website font sizes and div sizes are normal as i want them to look, But upon deployment to firebase they all appear bigger, both the font sizes and div sizes. On the console both have the same font size but on appearance, on the deployed website all elements appear bigger. I have tried to look for a solution online but have found none. What might be causing the discrepancy..

Answer (score 3):

Are you zoomed in for the Firebase host? Try pressing `<cmd> + 0` to reset the zoom level.